# Symfony2 Single app + multiple DB - handling cache and logs

Tags: symfony, saas

I have a SaaS application (software as a service) running on Symfony2. The architecture is a single codebase connecting to many different databases. One database per SaaS account. I have an additional database holding the SaaS account records including their DB credentials.

The DB credentials hardcoded in the parameters.yml file are for the database holding the SaaS account records.

Upon page load I have an Event Listener that looks at the subdomain part of the URL and looks up the record in the SaaS DB. If none exists, an exception is thrown. If an account is found, it loads the DB credentials for the client DB from the SaaS DB record and then closes the current DBAL connection and creates a new one to the client DB where the main application data resides.

All client account specific config is held in the client database and loaded as required. So my YAML config files are only holding configuration which is common to all SaaS accounts. All accounts use the same routing, the same templates, the same assets.

My question is, in this scenario can I use the same cache and log locations for all accounts, or will the cache for one SaaS account get polluted by another SaaS account?

Secondly, if the caches need to be separate for each client account, what would be the best way to specify a different cache location for each account? Via an environment variable perhaps? Obviously this can't be defined by a config parameter as the config itself is cached.

Thanks

Ben

Comment: I ended up splitting out the caches so that there was a different cache for each account. However, this is not very scalable as disk space usage and performance suffer when you have many clients. In the end, I grep'd through the cache files and just found a couple of instances where they were account specific, so I refactored my code to remove these and then reverted the system to use a single cache location for all SaaS accounts.